# How to solve Pde using integration

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve the PDE below using direct integration;
$$
u_{xt} = cos(2t), (x>0, t>0), u(x,0)=x, u(0,t)=0
$$
But when I change the integration order I realize that the resulting u(x,t) function also changes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Integrate first wrt $x$. $$u_t=x\cos(2t)+g(t)$$ Then integrate wrt $t$. $$u=\frac x2\sin(2t)+G(t)+f(x)$$ Now substitute the boundary conditions in which will allow you to determine G and f.